# Does the order of expressions separated by `/` have significance?

Tags: parsing, text-parsing, peg

I'm writing a parser for my interpreter, and as I was writing the peg rules, I hit this confusing case.

I got a rule like this

```
blank -> ()
    = " "*
    / "\n"*
```

For some reason, it doesn't match \n for me, but when I do the reverse

```
blank -> ()
    = "\n"*
    / " "*
```

It matches newlines, but doesn't match spacebars.

What is causing this? Shouldn't order do nothing but change the order expressions are tested in?. Is this an error in the peg implementation I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kleene star (`*`) matches *zero or more* repetitions. So `" "*` will always match; if there are no spaces, it will match zero spaces. In order for the next alternative to be tried, you need to use the *one or more* repetition operator, `+`.